# What is GCC doing to my static variable in a lambda?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, lambda, static

Using GCC 6.1, the following program:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    static const std::string foo {"foo"};
    std::vector<std::string> bars {{""}};
    std::cout << "foo outside: " << foo << std::endl;
    std::for_each(std::cbegin(bars), std::cend(bars), [] (const auto& bar) {
        std::cout << "foo inside: " << foo << std::endl;
    });
}
```

Prints:

```
foo outside: foo
foo inside:
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/eb845b3f6d3de17e)</kbd>**

What's going on?

Comment: I have no problems with gcc 6.2.1 and your code.

Comment: gcc dev team, all your bugware are belong to us

Comment: gcc 6.1.1 has no problem as well

Comment: GCC 5.4.0, can reproduce, so apparently it's been fixed after 6.1?

Comment: Wait, how is foo even visible there? Isn't this a non-capturing lambda?

Comment: @Cubic it's static so doesn't need capturing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug is already filed as Bug 69078 and yet unconfirmed.

See: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=69078